# How to check if an array contains integers or a string of integers

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a request from my api. The parameters can be an array like `["3456", "567564"]` (form data) or `"45643, 45645, 45645"` (json). These parameters are sent directly to a sql request. I have to check if a user sent only integers; otherwise SQL will crash: `> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "8939f"`.

For the moment, I have this:

```
def valid_group_params?
  group_ids_to_add = params[:group]['group_ids_to_add']
  group_ids_to_remove = params[:group]['group_ids_to_remove']
  if group_ids_to_add && group_ids_to_remove
    group_ids = group_ids_to_add + group_ids_to_remove
    if group_ids.is_a? Array
      group_ids = group_ids * ","
    else
      group_ids = group_ids_to_add + ',' + group_ids_to_remove
    end
    group_ids.split(',').all? {|x| x !~ /\D/ }
  end
end
```

but I don't like it that much. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, particularly after reading the other answers.  Would this help?

```
def all_digits?(params)
  case params
  when Array
    params
  when String
    params.split /,\s+/
  else
    # raise exception
  end.all? { |e| e =~ /^\d+$/ }
end

to_add = params[:group]['group_ids_to_add']
to_remove = params[:group]['group_ids_to_remove']
to_add && to_remove && all_digits?(to_ad) && all_digits?(to_remove)
```

**Case 1**

```
to_add    = ["123", "456"]
to_remove = ["789", "0cat"]

to_add && to_remove && all_digits?(to_add) && all_digits?(to_remove)
  #=> ["123", "456"] && ["789", "0cat"] && true && false
  #=> false
```

**Case 2**

```
to_add    = "123", "456"
to_remove = "789", "0cat"
to_add && to_remove && all_digits?(to_add) && all_digits?(to_remove)
  #=> "123", "456" && "789", "0cat" && true && false
  #=> false
```

Comment: You write. I prefere to lock the user ability to use only correct parameters. I love what you did.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) to convert string into integer.

As per official doc:

> Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. If
>   there is not a valid number at the start of str, 0 is returned.

Eg:

```
"45643".to_i
# => 45643
"8939f".to_i
# => 8939 
"99 red balloons".to_i 
# => 99
```

If even this is not sufficient, you can always use regex:

```
"some1221text"[/\d+/]
# => "1221"
```

Comment: That's an idea too. Thanks for it. The only problem was when it was only letters. You get 0. But that something my sql request can understand. Thanks @shivam

Comment: @BeniMio worst case you can always use regex. Here: `"some1221text"[/\d+/] # => "1221"`

Comment: now I'm gonna try to turn it to something clean. :)

Comment: `to_i` doesn't check if a string is a valid integer. How would you use it in `valid_group_params?`

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_i` method.

```
foo = "3456"
foo.to_i
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the global method [Kernel#Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

```
Integer("123")    # => 123
Integer(123)      # => 123
```

This is much like #to_i, in that it will convert a string to an integer and leave an integer unchanged.  However, unlike #to_i, #Integer will raise an error if its argument does not represent an integer:

```
Integer("abc")    # => ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "abc"
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't know I was able to use it. Thanks